# Pass html un-order list value to c# textbox and use in sqlquery

Tags: c#, javascript, html, sql

This is the javascript I use to set a text to a certain value

```
document.getElementById('Original Map').addEventListener('click', function () {
    map.setView([52.42922, -18.5154], 5);
    var text = document.getElementById("mytext");
    text.value = "Original Map";
});
```

This is the html

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server" >
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <li><label><h5>Now Selected: </h5></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="mytext" runat="server" ReadOnly style=" font-size:15px;  border:0px; " BackColor="White" ForeColor="#6699FF"></asp:TextBox></li>
            <li><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" style ="border-radius:5px; width:100px; padding:5px;" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Button1_click" /></li> 
        </li>
    </ul>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Black" BorderColor="White">
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

This is the c# code

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\mduggan\Documents\Database1.accdb");

public string TextBoxValue
{
    get { return mytext.Text; }
    set { mytext.Text = value; }
}   

protected void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filldata();
}

protected void filldata()
{
    string query;
    query = TextBoxValue;

    if (query != null)
    {
        con.Open();
        string str = "SELECT PageID, PageName FROM Maps WHERE PageName ='" + query + "'";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else 
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Why does the query variable (in .cs class) not pick up the TextBoxValue value coming from a HTML Unorder list.

The value from the list is transferred over to the text box, but then the query variable does not detect any value in the text box and zero results are shown on the sqlquery returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because your textbox is set to readonly which may cause the object not to be sent back to the server on click.
source: http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/how-to-get-the-readonly-textbox-value-on-the-server